# VSE Audio Strip Modifier, using the Equalizer

Tags: modifiers, audio

Happy New Year!

How does one properly apply the equalizer modifier in an Audio strip?

In particular, this "Copy to Selected Strips" option. The various things I've tried appear to make no obvious audio difference.

What I'm after is a simple recipe for making a 240Hz cut.